# What's the best way to work with a Java String that has a mapping of fields within it?

Tags: java, string

I have a long String that has a particular field layout:

```
Char 1-6 = the type of message
Char 7 = system number
Char 8-9 = unused
Char 10 = shift number
and so on
```

I understand that I can just use the String methods to work with this, but am hoping that there is something a bit better that will let me associate the fields with the positions in a more meaningful way.

Does this exist? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well you could create a Class with all the properties the original String contains, when you create an object of that class you pass it the source string, parse it and save each value to the appropriate class field. You will always need to use the String methods to do so.

Comment: I would take a class approach so that usability and readability would be better.

Comment: Agreed. Passing of the String to a Class that handles all this is probably the neatest way that allows you to pass everything around, and all the string parsing is in the background.

Comment: Please add class solution so I can pick it. I have done this before and was hoping for better. What do you think of the jsefa answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a custom class with variables each defining the type of information they represent. In the constructor for that class, pass this String and initialise the values of different fields by parsing the String. You can then seamlessly access the information the different parts of your String represents.

You can also save the original String in the object of this new class, in case the information regarding the original String is required.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but this should work:

```
String typeOfMessage = str.substring(0,5);
char systemNumber  =   str.charAt(6);
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jsefa` `@FlrDataType` ... for fix length record...

that way you can create a class and easily define the positions

```
@FlrDataType
public class MyMessage {

   @FlrField(pos = 1, length = 5)
   String messageType;

   @FlrField(pos = 6, length = 1)
   String systemNumber;

   //etc
}
```

here is a quick tutorial http://jsefa.sourceforge.net/quick-tutorial.html